# Can a normal jet bridge reach an upper deck?

Tags: ground-operations, boeing-747, airbus-a380

We have planes with an upper deck since the time the B747 was born. Now we have the A380. I wonder if a normal jet bridge can reach the upper deck of both planes? The scenario in my mind is if an A380 has to divert somewhere that does not normally serve the A380, can a normal facility be used? Or does a passenger have to walk down the internal stair to exit via the lower deck?

[Related news](https://www.nationmultimedia.com/thailand/general/40019879)

Comment: [here are some details about the doors on the 747 and A380](https://simpleflying.com/why-dont-boeing-747s-board-on-the-upper-deck/); not an answer, of course.

Comment: The A-380 is *such* a different beast that they basically have their standard divert airfields, and anything not on the list is a huge big deal... as in, the taxiways may not be stressed or have wingspan clearance for them. So getting a jetbridge to the *upper* deck is probably far down the list of concerns in that situation. If you must deplane, maybe just getting everybody off thru the lower deck is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Jet bridge capability varies by design.  Some airports are equipped for this while others are not.  A diversion to an airport not listed in the airline's procedures would be considered only in the most time-critical emergency.